# Define a variable in the .environment file and use (refrence) that in the .sh file

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, mkdir

I have written a bash script to create a folder if it doesn't already exist and have set the variables in my environment file and referenced that in my .sh file

Below is my script I have added the variables in the .sh file which I have added in my environment file.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d "$checkfolder" ]; then
  mkdir -p "$createfolder";
fi
```

I have set the following environment variables in my /etc/environment file

```
checkfolder=/home/ubuntu/hello23
createfolder=/home/ubuntu/hello23
```

when I execute the script I am getting the following errors:

```
ubuntu@:~/cicd$ ./createfolder.sh 
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory
```

Here is the normal script I have written, which  works and creates a folder if it does not exist

```
if [ ! -d /home/ubuntu/hello ]; then
  mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/hello;
fi
```

What is the issue here and what changes should i make?

Comment: your variable is empty. not sure what you are trying to achieve but simple mkdir -p would be enough (no need to test). but when testing you should at least use the same variable

Comment: @BilalYousaf : You would have to create a new login shell (`bash --login`) to cause `/etc/environment` to be read. This is described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/664169/what-is-the-difference-between-etc-environment-and-etc-profile). Alternatively you can change the first line in your script to `#!/bin/bash -l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/environment` and `~/.pam_environment` are read when you log in. If you've just edited those files, your changes don't apply to the current session.

If you want to apply the changes to your current session, you can run

```
. /etc/environment
```

to set the variables in your current shell. This only works if the values of the variables don't contain any shell speciavairablel characters (spaces, `` ()[]{}\|&;<>~*?'"`$# `` and I may be forgetting a few), because the syntax of `/etc/environment` is only an approximation of the syntax of the shell.

If you've added new variables, and not just changed their value, you'll also need to export them (`VAR=value` in the shell only creates a shell variable, not an environment variable).

```
export MY_HOME checkfolder createfolder
```

or more generally

```
export $(sed -n 's/^\([A-Za-z0-9_]*\)=.*/\1/p')
```

There is no file that sets the environment for every new program, because that would defeat the point of the environment, which is that every process has its own which it inherits from its parents. If there was a “global environment file”, it would make it impossible to run programs with a different environment. If you want a global configuration, read a configuration file:

```
if [ -e ~/.my_application_configuration.sh ]; then
  . ~/.my_application_configuration.sh
fi
```

There is a way to have a file that sets the environment *for every bash script* (only bash scripts, not sh scripts): put the full path to the file in the environment variable `BASH_ENV`. As I explained just above, this is usually a bad idea.

Comment: i. have. applied those changes to my current session. as you. suggested. However, i am still getting the same error: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory.

Comment: @BilalYousaf Sorry, I'd forgotten a step if you've added a new variable. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you, that. has worked for me, appreciate it  :)